# Android - PopupWindow above a specific view

Tags: android, popupwindow

I am developing an application for Android and I am using a popup window when the user clicks a specific menu bar object(consisting of small images lined up horizontally) on the bottom of the screen.

On the click I want the popup window to be anchored to the top-left corner of the view that was clicked and be shown on top.

The only methods that seem to be relevant are *showAsDropDown(View anchor, int xoff, int yoff)* and *showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)*.  The problem with showAsDropDown is that it is anchored to the bottom-left corner of the view.

Is there another way to implement this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`popupWindow.showAtLocation(...)` actually shows the window absolutely positioned on the *screen* (not even the application). The anchor in that call is only used for its window token. The coordinates are offsets from the given gravity.

What you actually want to use is:

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, offsetX, offsetY, gravity);
```

This call is only available in API 19+, so in earlier versions you need to use:

```
popupWindow.showAsDropdown(anchor, offsetX, offsetY);
```

These calls show the popup window relative to the specified anchor view. Note that the default gravity (when calling without specified gravity) is `Gravity.TOP|Gravity.START` so if you are explicitly using `Gravity.LEFT` in various spots in your app you will have a bad time :)

Comment: That's the one I was looking for. All you need to calculate is the offset according to the ui element you use..

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a sample Kotlin code which will show a `PopupWindow` above the anchor view.

```
private fun showPopupWindow(anchor: View) {
    PopupWindow(anchor.context).apply {
        isOutsideTouchable = true
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(anchor.context)
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null).apply {
            measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            )
        }
    }.also { popupWindow ->
        // Absolute location of the anchor view
        val location = IntArray(2).apply {
            anchor.getLocationOnScreen(this)
        }
        val size = Size(
            popupWindow.contentView.measuredWidth,
            popupWindow.contentView.measuredHeight
        )
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(
            anchor,
            Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START,
            location[0] - (size.width - anchor.width) / 2,
            location[1] - size.height
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer and it's working fine.

Comment: 100% working solution  but it shows some background color how to remove that ?

Comment: @GulabSagevadiya You need to set/clear popup window background color: `popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))`

Comment: Great answer. It was helpful to me too.

Answer (score 10):

You just needed to move the popupWindow by the height of its anchor using the *yoff* parameter in the *showAsDropDown(View anchor, int xoff, int yoff)* syntax.

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, 0, -anchor.getHeight()+popupView.getHeight);
```

Also, be aware that if the max height allowed to anchor does not allow for the transformation, the popup might not show up properly.

Comment: Please elaborate on how this code answers the question (this answer was in the Low Quality Posts review queue).

Answer (score 7):

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, anchor.getHeight());
```

Comment: You need to add parent view instead of anchor and also need to pass the exact location of the popup where you want to place it.

Answer (score 6):

I have this code: **PopupWindow below a specific view (Gravity End) for all sdk version.**

```
        // display the popup[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0, Gravity.END);
        } else {
            mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(v, v.getWidth() - mPopupWindow.getWidth(), 0);
        }
```

Here View v is ImageButton Calendar.

Comment: This worked great for me. I was using showAtLocation for SDK >= 24, but it didn't work for all devices. This worked for every device I tested so far.

Answer (score 5):

The one you want to use is `showAtLocation(...)`. You specify the anchor view (the one the user clicks), and position it relative to that via the `gravity` parameter and offsets. Think of the `gravity` parameter like the `PopupWindow` is almost like a child view and the parent view is like a container layout.

You should be able to put `Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP` as the parameter.

Comment: No such luck, the PopupWindow will show top-left corner of the window with that line (popupWindow.showAsLocation(anchor, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0)).

Answer (score 4):

you can display the popup always above the anchor by following

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, 0, -anchor.getHeight()-popupView.getHeight);
```

Comment: not working. Popup is showing from the bottom of screen

Answer (score 3):

Sample example:

```
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(context);
popupWindow.setContentView(scrollView);
scrollView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),                 
View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
int he=scrollView.getMeasuredHeight();
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(items,0, -items.getHeight()-he);
```

Answer (score 0):

After using so many solutions, I got one solution to display the **PopupWindow** above any **View** in **Kotlin**.

To display the popup window above the view, you can use the **showAsDropDown()** function.

```
popUp.showAsDropDown(v, 0, (-0.2 * v.height).roundToInt(), Gravity.CENTER)
```

With:

- **v:** View(Anchor)
- **0:** offSetX
- **(-0.2 * v.height).roundToInt():** offSetY
- **Gravity.CENTER:** Gravity

For example: https://medium.com/@bhattmeet887/popupwindow-above-the-specific-view-kotlin-ab1a199581eb

Answer (score 0):

Here's using the android-x solution, which should even work in case you have a floating UI using SAW permission (System Alert Window) :

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private fun showPopupWindow(anchor: View) {
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(anchor.context)
    popupWindow.isFocusable = true
    popupWindow.inputMethodMode = PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED
    popupWindow.contentView = LayoutInflater.from(anchor.context).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null)
    PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(popupWindow, anchor, 0, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM)
}
```

This is for alignment of bottom-left.

If you need bottom-center, you could use this, for example:

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
private fun showPopupWindow(anchor: View) {
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(anchor.context)
    popupWindow.isFocusable = true
    popupWindow.inputMethodMode = PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(anchor.context)
    val contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null)
    contentView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
    popupWindow.contentView = contentView
    PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(popupWindow, anchor, (anchor.measuredWidth - contentView.measuredWidth) / 2, 0, Gravity.BOTTOM)
}
```

Answer (score -5):

popupwindow.showAsDropDown(anchor,0, -125);
this thing work for me

Comment: this is specific only for your case

Comment: Do not hardcode an specify value only for your case