# Show PopupWindow above a particular view

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

I am trying to show a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) above relative layout.

```
 popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout,  Gravity.BOTTOM
            |Gravity.CENTER, 0, layout);
```

Where layout is a relative layout.But it appears only at the bottom.Not above the relativelayout. I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818146/android-popupwindow-above-a-specific-view).But it didn't helped.

Here is my PopupWindow layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/nearbyplace_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_school"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@string/school"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_school"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_college"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@string/college"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_college"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_hospital"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@string/hospital"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_hospital"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_shoppingmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="@string/shoppingmall"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_shoppingmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My main layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_static_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- <RelativeLayout
                 android:id="@+id/rl_get_nearby"
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="0.99"
                 android:background="@color/lightGrey">

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/tv_neighbour"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_view_map"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:text=" View On Map"
                     android:textSize="14sp" />
             </RelativeLayout>

             <View
                 android:layout_width="0dp"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="0.02"
                 android:background="@color/grey" />-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.99"
                android:background="@color/lightGrey">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_area"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Soham"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your last argument should not be layout, it's supposed to be y offset.

Comment: @jimmy0251 What should be the y offset .?

Comment: It is popup's y location offset from anchor view.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this method to do this

```
private void displayPopupWindow(View anchorView) {
        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(Pdf.this);
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_content, null);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        // Set content width and height
        popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popup.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        // Closes the popup window when touch outside of it - when looses focus
        popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup.setFocusable(true);
        popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        // Show anchored to button
        popup.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,
                anchorView.getBottom() - 60);

        popup.showAsDropDown(anchorView);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not Working,coming at the top of the window

Comment: i test for your every child linear layout its working fine

Comment: I have added my main layout.I am showing popupwindow clicking on the id layout

Comment: i have changed the answer change Gravity.Bottom

Comment: I have already tried that and it was showing at the bottom,not above the layout i want. ):

Comment: Still same problem.I am testing on android one mobile.By the way I am calling function to like this displayPopupWindow(layout).

Comment: does it works for relative layout? it is not working