# How to set click event on a triangular view (as in the given image shapes)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue regarding design 'Setting screen' for my app. In this screen I need to design circular menu options in a triangular shape and I need to set `OnClickListener` only on the triangular area, which is only visible option border area. I can't understand what approach I need to use to achieve this design as well as set `OnClickListener`.

[image]

Comment: can you share xml file for this for better understanding

Comment: @Pranita i haven't design it yet, because i'm not understand how it will design?

Comment: You asked a question which has another question i.e. Did you manage to design it? Clicklistener is easy once you design it. Try to divide a linear layout into parts and then create a triangle layout like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43738456/5339829

Comment: there are many ways how to do this. My first approach would be to create a custom View that contains the whole menu. In this view you can intercept touch events with their x and y coordinate and use this to match the touch to one of the menu items.