# PopupWindow: show it just above a given View

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I've got a Button, and upon clicking it I would like to show a PopupWindow. 
The Window should be displayed just above the Button.

I have read: [Android - PopupWindow above a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818146/android-popupwindow-above-a-specific-view)

where the approved answer is

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, 0, -anchor.getHeight()-popupView.getHeight);
```

but the trouble is, I don't know what's the height of my popupWindow - it is created programatically, and before calling the `showAsDropDown` its `getHeight` method returns -2 ( WRAP_CONTENT? ).

If I use appropriate constant like so

```
popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, 0, -anchor.getHeight()-530, Gravity.LEFT);
```

then it works. The question is thus more precisely 'how do I display a programatically created PopupWindow of height `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` above a given anchor View?'